# overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark – Does not work when presenting a view controller modally – iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller, ios-darkmode

This code works fine for all other screens except for the one being presented modally. I have checked that the line that changes the User Interface Style is executed however, the interface style still doesn't change.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let filename :String = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("theme.txt").path
    do {
        let data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: filename, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        theme = String(data)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
    
    if theme == "Dark" {
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    }
        
    else if theme == "Light" {
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just created a sample project and I can't reproduce the descriped behaviour. Do you really want to execute ```overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark``` regardless of whether ```theme``` is "Dark" or "Light"? And I would suggest, to move the code into ```viewDidLoad``` because otherwise you will have a short delay between the transition from light to dark mode (or dark to light).

Comment: I am so stupid. I was meant to have .light. How did I not realise this. Thanks a lot. And yes, I have a delay when changing mode. Maybe putting it in ViewWillAppear will be better.

Comment: Happy to help :-)...